# Android ignores switch statement (code not executable)

Tags: android

I added a toolbar and started to implement `onOptionsItemSelected` method. The action did not work though. I debugged the program and I found that the `switch` statement is ignored. If I implement the logic as `if`, it works. The code is compiled, I can see changes but Studio shows that the code within `switch` is not executable. I have no idea why.

[image]

Code as requested:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    Log.d(logTag, "onOptionsItemSelected()");
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_level) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "If!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            return true;
    }
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.action_settings: {
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.action_level: {
            return true;
        }
        default: {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Default", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try Build -> Rebuild Project ?

Comment: Yes, I rebuilt it. And I wrote that I can see changes in the code, so it must have been compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer add answer , First there no difference between `if` and `switch` I can consider switch nested if .. else statement

in your case you called if `(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_level)` and switch you call `R.id.action_settings`

provide your menu file to make sure both ids included

second just rebuild if you make any changes before run app (recommended)

Last thing why you return true in switch statement you should make `break;`

Comment: Good point with return/break. I switched to switch and I noticed that breakpoints in it are catchable. I have no idea why breakpoint on return does not work.

Comment: if you want to test try log it ex Log.i(TAG ,"setting option");

Answer (score 1):

Try the following options:

- adding more logic to your switch statement
- use the **File/Invalidate Caches** option to see if problem continues
- cleaning and rebuilding the solution again
- check for updates on your current IDE version
- check for update on the API level version that you are currently using and make sure is updated in your current IDE.

Also if a **switch** statement does not have more than 3 options an **if** might perform better and be more readable

Comment: Yes, I rebuilt it. And I wrote that I can see changes in the code, so it must have been compiled

Comment: Leos I have added more options and alternatives, pleas test them and let me know